# C++ - Iterating over a tuple & resolution of type vs constant parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, enable-if

I'm currently in the process of writing arithmetic operator overloads for tuples. The operator iterates over the tuple to perform the operation on each of its individual element. Here is the definition for operator +=:

```
template< typename... Ts, std::size_t I = 0 >
inline typename std::enable_if< I == sizeof... (Ts), std::tuple< Ts... >& >::type operator +=(std::tuple< Ts... >& lhs, const std::tuple< Ts... >& rhs)
{
    return lhs;
}

template< typename... Ts, std::size_t I = 0 >
inline typename std::enable_if< I != sizeof... (Ts), std::tuple< Ts... >& >::type operator +=(std::tuple< Ts... >& lhs, const std::tuple< Ts... >& rhs)
{
    std::get< I >(lhs) += std::get< I >(rhs);
    return operator +=< Ts..., I + 1 >(lhs, rhs);
}
```

Unfortunately, when I attempt to call the operator, GCC 4.6 cannot decide which overload it should use. For example:

```
std::tuple< int, int, int, int > a = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3, 4), b = std::make_tuple(5, 6, 7, 8);
a += b;
```

Yields the following error:

```
:/Workspace/raster/main.cpp:833:7:   instantiated from here
C:/Workspace/raster/main.cpp:809:45: error: no matching function for call to 'operator+=(std::tuple<int, int, int, int>&, const std::tuple<int, int, int, int>&)'
C:/Workspace/raster/main.cpp:809:45: note: candidates are:
C:/Workspace/raster/main.cpp:800:151: note: template<class ... Ts, unsigned int I> typename std::enable_if<(I == sizeof (Ts ...)), std::tuple<_TElements ...>&>::type operator+=(std::tuple<_TElements ...>&, const std::tuple<_TElements ...>&)
C:/Workspace/raster/main.cpp:806:83: note: template<class ... Ts, unsigned int I> typename std::enable_if<(I != sizeof (Ts ...)), std::tuple<_TElements ...>&>::type operator+=(std::tuple<_TElements ...>&, const std::tuple<_TElements ...>&)
```

Which is strange since the `std::enable_if` condition should reject the inappropriate call. For now, I have the following workaround which was actually my prior implementation. The above version is in fact a simplification attempt.

```
template< std::size_t I, typename... Ts >
inline typename std::enable_if< I == sizeof... (Ts), std::tuple< Ts... >& >::type assignadd_impl(std::tuple< Ts... >& lhs, const std::tuple< Ts... >& rhs)
{
    return lhs;
}

template< std::size_t I, typename... Ts >
inline typename std::enable_if< I != sizeof... (Ts), std::tuple< Ts... >& >::type assignadd_impl(std::tuple< Ts... >& lhs, const std::tuple< Ts... >& rhs)
{
    std::get< I >(lhs) += std::get< I >(rhs);
    return assignadd_impl< I + 1, Ts... >(lhs, rhs);
}

template< typename... Ts >
inline std::tuple< Ts... >& operator +=(std::tuple< Ts... >& lhs, const std::tuple< Ts... >& rhs)
{
    return assignadd_impl< 0, Ts... >(lhs, rhs);
}
```

This compiles and works as expected. Why does the simplified version refuse to compile? Thanks.

Comment: What if you move the `I` template parameter to the front in your first code sample, like it is in the second one that works?  Does that change anything?

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock - Unfortunately no. I tried many variations, including switching the order of the template parameters, but all of them yield the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using explicitly specified template arguments to a function or class template requires that any template parameter packs appear at the end of the overall template parameter list.  Moving `Ts...` to the end of the template parameter lists and changing the calls appropriately makes the code work.  Section 14.8.2.1 of [the current C++0x draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3126.pdf) states that parameter packs that are not at the end of the template parameter list cannot be deduced from a function call (which makes your original code fail), but explicitly specifying all of the template arguments to `operator+=` in all cases still causes a SFINAE error.  [A previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706677/partial-template-specialization-with-multiple-template-parameter-packs) has a link to the exact text forbidding it; [IBM's documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v111v131/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp111.linux.doc/language_ref/variadic_templates.html) says that it is an error as well.

Comment: It does work indeed. I don't know what went wrong during my original tests because I had inverted template arguments at one point. But thank you nonetheless. :)