# C++ How to store a parameter pack as a variable

Tags: c++

At the moment I am having trouble trying to store a parameter pack, this is example code of the design:

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
void handleFunc(Func func, Args&&... args) {
    struct nest {
        Func nestFunc;
        Args... nestArgs; // I DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO HERE
        void setup(Func func, Args... args) {
            nestFunc = func;
            nestArgs = (args)...; // SO I CAN SET IT HERE
        }
        // Later I will forward this and run the function with its arguments
        unsigned process() {
            nestFunc(std::forward<Args>(nestArgs)...); // USE IT HERE
            return 0;
        }
    };
    nest* myNest;
    myNest->setup(func, (args)...);
}
```

This is an example of everything involved for the problem, I need to store the arguments for **later** invoke in my nest struct. Also, if you have a solution to store it but to set it is different to mine, please also let me know about that too. Thanks.

Comment: `std::tuple<Args...>` - also, `std::bind` and `std::function` and all that fun stuff.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to "store" a template parameter pack without expanding it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691657/is-it-possible-to-store-a-template-parameter-pack-without-expanding-it)

Answer (score 25):

**Edit from 2018**: In C++17 the answer to this question is different. You still have to store your arguments in a `::std::tuple`, but when the time comes to call the function [`::std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) handles unpacking this tuple and calling the function for you. And if you need to use the indices trick for something other than what `::std::apply` does, there's [`::std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) and the associated helper function, `::std::make_index_sequence` that you should investigate.

Now back to your C++11/14 answer from way back in 2013.

You have to use `::std::tuple<Args...>` to store it. But then the question is how to unpack it when you need it. For that you need to use a technique called 'indices'.

So, here is a link to a place where I've done approximately what you're looking to do. The most relevant class here that's sort of the centerpiece is `suspended_call`.

https://bitbucket.org/omnifarious/sparkles/src/tip/sparkles/deferred.hpp?at=default

In just a bit, I'll extract the most relevant bits and put them in terms of your code.

[This line](https://bitbucket.org/omnifarious/sparkles/src/d78af18c74b812d54f7e20146f465c9002a804a7/sparkles/deferred.hpp?at=default#cl-338):

```
auto saved_args = ::std::make_tuple(::std::move(args)...);
```

saves the arguments into a tuple. I used `::std::move` there, and I think that's the right thing to do. But it's possible I'm wrong and I should use `::std::forward`. I've never been clear on the exact difference aside from signaling intent.

The code that actually does the call with the saved arguments can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/omnifarious/sparkles/src/d78af18c74b812d54f7e20146f465c9002a804a7/sparkles/deferred.hpp?at=default#cl-208). Now that code is fairly specific to exactly what I'm doing. The bit that implements the indices trick involves creating a pack of integers that maps to the indices to use as arguments the `::std::get<I>` template. Once you have this pack of integers, you can then use it to expand the call to `::std::get` to get all the tuple elements as individual arguments.

I'll try to come up with code that does that in a relatively straightforward way:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template < ::std::size_t... Indices>
struct indices {};

template < ::std::size_t N, ::std::size_t... Is>
struct build_indices : build_indices<N-1, N-1, Is...>
{};

template < ::std::size_t... Is>
struct build_indices<0, Is...> : indices<Is...>
{};

template <typename FuncT, typename ArgTuple, ::std::size_t... Indices>
auto call(const FuncT &f, ArgTuple &&args, const indices<Indices...> &)
   -> decltype(f(::std::get<Indices>(::std::forward<ArgTuple>(args))...))
{
   return ::std::move(f(::std::get<Indices>(::std::forward<ArgTuple>(args))...));
}

template <typename FuncT, typename ArgTuple>
auto call(const FuncT &f, ArgTuple &&args)
     -> decltype(call(f, args,
                      build_indices< ::std::tuple_size<ArgTuple>::value>{}))
{
    const build_indices< ::std::tuple_size<ArgTuple>::value> indices;

    return ::std::move(call(f, ::std::move(args), indices));
}

int myfunc(::std::string name, const unsigned int foo)
{
   return 0;
}

int foo(::std::tuple< ::std::string, const unsigned int> saved_args)
{
   return call(myfunc, ::std::move(saved_args));
}
```

A lot of this code was borrowed from [this page on the indices trick](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks:indices).

Also, that's sort of a sample that you will have to adapt slightly to your specific situation. Basically, just call `call(nestFunc, saved_args)` somewhere.

Comment: How would set this tuple with (args)...;

Comment: Can you elaborate more on these "indicies"?

Comment: @David: Yes, more examples. You shall have them. I actually had to write code that did this recently.

Comment: @Omnifarious, Interesting, I was just thinking if it would be possible to store a parameter pack for later expansion. Would your code work to, say, store a callable object along with a list of arguments for later calling?

Comment: @Omnifarious, Sweet, that actually fills in for some uses I've been wanting. Honestly, the best I had, from quite a while ago, was a `std::function<void()>` (It wouldn't need a return value) with bound arguments.

Comment: Ok, so far using a tuple to store args, I've added:
`std::tuple<Args...> nestArgs;`
setting the tuple:
`nestArgs = std::tuple<Args...>(args...);` OR
`nestArgs = std::make_tuple(args...);`
Now it's a case of forwarding it to the function...

Comment: @Luka: I added an example of how to do the forwarding. Again, I used `::std::move`. Not positive that's the right thing to do, but I think it is.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I must say though, I came across this not long ago, just figured it out and it applies the same thing your solution gives: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766112/c11-i-can-go-from-multiple-args-to-tuple-but-can-i-go-from-tuple-to-multiple)

Comment: @Luka: Yep. :-) Perhaps I should've pointed you there. I was enjoying the mental exercise of figuring out how it worked again. The original (I think) example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer

Answer (score 18):

I know it's been a while but I had similar needs and came up with this solution, hope it helps someone:

```
#include <functional>

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
struct nest {
    std::function<void()> callBack;

    void setup(Func func1, Args... args) {
        callBack = [func1, args...]()
        {
            (func1)(args...);
        };
    }

    unsigned process() {
        callBack();
        return 0;
    }
};

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
void handleFunc(Func func, Args&&... args) {
    nest<Func, Args...> myNest;
    myNest.setup(func, args...);
}
```

Comment: clever workaround for the insanely crippled C++ pack syntax )

Comment: Storing them all inside a lambda instead of in a tuple is very clever.

Comment: Though using generalized lambda capture expressions to forward all of the arguments (and then also forward them in the call inside the lambda) might be a better idea.

Comment: Does this implement perfect forwarding?

Comment: This really solved my 2 days of finding ... Thanks