# Factory class with variadic template arguments for constructor

Tags: c++, templates

I'm attempting to design a factory class that allows me to encapsulate the construction of any class (that has been derived from the same base class "Base"), with any number of constructor arguments. The current design only supports one or zero constructor arguments:

```
class FactoryBase
{
public:
    FactoryBase(std::string id) : id_(id) {}
    virtual ~FactoryBase(){}
    virtual Base* create() const = 0;
    std::string getId() const { return id_; }
protected:
    std::string id_;
};

template<class T, typename A> //One argument
class Factory : public FactoryBase
{
public:
    Factory(std::string id, A arg) : FactoryBase(id), arg_(arg) {}
    Base* create() const { return new T(arg_); }
private:
    A arg_;
};

template<class T> //zero arguments/default ctor
class Factory<T,void> : public FactoryBase
{
public:
    Factory(std::string id) : FactoryBase(id) {}
    Base* create() const { return new T(); }
};
```

I could just add one template specialization for each number of arguments, but I'd like to learn how to do it "porperly".

Comment: Yeah, couldn't fix "variadric" to variadic, drove me mad

Comment: Shouldn't `: FactoryBase(id) {}` in the base class be `: id_(id)`?

Comment: FactoryBase::id_ must be initialized in all cases, and in order to enforce that I put it's value as a FactoryBase constructor argument, while providing no default constructor for FactoryBase, so constructors of all derived classes must provide the ID value.

Comment: I meant that in the base class you're recursively calling the constructor `FactoryBase(id)` in the initializer list. That looks like infinite recursion to me.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The excerpt is not from the original program, so I made a mistake while creating the example code. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Sorry. I misread your post. I will make a new answer.

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate, that result did not show up in my search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking from the information I gave in the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868129/how-to-store-variadic-template-arguments/16868151#16868151), you need to store the types of your arguments in a type list. In C++11 this would be `std::tuple`. Your class template should take a parameter pack of arguments that are placed into this tuple.

The constructor should be a template constructor that takes a parameter pack, which you then forward to the constructor of the tuple data member.

A compile-time integer sequence generator can be used to access each element of the tuple within `create()` (see the exact code in the duplicate).

Comment: Is it possible to deduce the `Factory` type from the constructor arguments? I'd like to be able to do the following: `Factory<SomeClass> fac1("ID123","arg0", 1.56, 4);` instead of `Factory<SomeClass,std::string,double,std::string> fac2("ID123","arg0", 1.56, 4);`.

Comment: Of course something like `Factory<SomeClass> fac1 = makeFactory<SomeClass>("ID123","arg0", 1.56, 4);` would work, but a proper construcor would be neat instead of some external function.

Comment: @user1062874 Sorry but in order for the constructor to work the types have to be known beforehand. This is because the tuple data member needs to have the types specified before the arguments can be forwarded to its constructor. This is why I suggested making a helper function which deduced the types from its parameters.