# C++: How to distinguish between a reference to a class member and a reference to an ordinary variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, rtti, type-traits, typeinfo

Is there any possible way to determine whether a reference variable refers to a class member (and then determine which class it belongs to) instead of an ordinary variable? Here's a simple example that hopefully shows what I'm getting at:

```
class A
{
    private:
        unsigned int x;

    public:
        A() : x(15) { }
        unsigned int& GetX() { return x; }
};

int main( void )
{
    A a;
    unsigned int y = 12;
    unsigned int& yr = y;
    unsigned int& xr = a.GetX();

    // Is there anyway of identifying, using typeid() or something
    // similar, whether xr refers to x inside class A or is its type
    // completely indistinguishable from that of yr? i.e. does its type
    // information contain anything along the lines of    
    // typeid(xr).name() == "A::unsigned int&" that identifies it as 
    // belonging to class A?

    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

> No, there's no way to so distinguish. Why would you want to? Sounds
>   suspiciously like an XY problem.

OK, perhaps my example was too simplistic and maybe I'm not asking the right the question so let me give you a more detailed example:

Considering class A above. In most cases I would want to use the getter method to just query the value of x thus returning a constant reference is usually what is needed (in my real code x is actually a very large vector or matrix so returning by value might be slow). But in some special cases I may want to be able to change the value of x - i.e. inside of a user specified function that is binded to a function wrapper as per a previous question: [C++: Generic function wrapper class as a member of a non-template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40297183/c-generic-function-wrapper-class-as-a-member-of-a-non-template-class/40298291#40298291). So, when binding the function to the function wrapper, the argument that will be modified by the user function is supplied using the getter method and a helper class to remove the const qualifier, e.g.

```
A.BindFunc( UserFunc, WriteAccess::GetNonConstRef( A.GetX() ) );
```

where the `WriteAccess` helper class is as follows:

```
class WriteAccess
{
    public:

        template <typename T>
        static T& GetNonConstRef( const T& x )
        {
            return const_cast<T&>(x);
        }
};
```

And the user supplied function might be:

```
void UserFunc( unsigned int& X )
{
    X = somethingelse;
}
```

However, I would like to prevent the `WriteAccess::GetNonConstRef()` method from being used with any old class member, and only allow it to be used with members of class A (and derived classes). So I was wondering if there is anyway to determine, inside `WriteAccess::GetNonConstRef()`, which class the supplied reference belongs to so that either it doesn't compile or execution is terminated if a different class is used.

So I was thinking if there is some way to distinguish between references to ordinary variables and those of class members (and indeed references to members of class A and references to members of other classes) then this might help me.

Comment: No, there's no way to so distinguish. Why would you want to? Sounds suspiciously like [an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Adding `int& A::GetX()` seems simpler...

Comment: BTW, you may have `const int& ref = cond ? y : a.GetX();`

Comment: Have you considered just making a Getter that returns a non-const reference and using that instead of creating a function to remove const?

Comment: @Kian Well, sure. But that would be too easy wouldn't it? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to distinguish between a reference to a class member and a reference to an ordinary variable?

In general, this is impossible. A reference doesn't hold the information of an objects container. A sub-object is indistinguishable from a stand alone object.

`typeid` will not be of any help. The fully qualified name of a variable is not part of the type name of the variable.

---

However, it is possible to test whether a reference (or a pointer) refers to a particular member of a particular container instance:

```
bool xr_refers_to_x_of_a = &xr == &a.GetX(); // true
```