# Store variadic arguments in class template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to make some manager that will work with tasks after some timeout or at some time etc. For this manager I'm developing task classes that I can save in this manager and execute later on. So far I've got these classes, but there is an error during compilation. Because I'm newbie in templates, I can't figure out where is the problem. Everything is just fine, except creating task from class object. But if the method in those object will not have parameters, everything will be fine. I used also code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868129/how-to-store-variadic-template-arguments). So, my code is:

```
class TaskInterface
{
public:
    virtual void Execute() = 0;
};

//************************************************************

namespace TaskHelper
{
    template <std::size_t... Types>
    struct index {};

    template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Types>
    struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N - 1, N - 1, Types...> {};

    template <std::size_t... Types>
    struct gen_seq<0, Types...> : index<Types...>{};
}

//************************************************************

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Types>
class SimpleTask : public TaskInterface
{
public:
    template <typename Function>
    SimpleTask(Function&& func, Types&&... args)
        : m_function(std::forward<Function>(func)),
        m_args(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Types>(args)...)) {
    }

    void Execute() override final
    {
        func(m_args);
    }

private:
    std::function<ReturnType(Types...)> m_function;
    std::tuple<Types...> m_args;

    template <typename... Args, std::size_t... Is>
    void func(std::tuple<Args...>& tup, TaskHelper::index<Is...>)
    {
        m_function(std::get<Is>(tup)...);
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    void func(std::tuple<Args...>& tup)
    {
        func(tup, TaskHelper::gen_seq<sizeof...(Args)>{});
    }
};

//************************************************************

template < typename ReturnType, class Class, typename... Types>
class MemberTask : public TaskInterface
{
public:
    typedef ReturnType(Class::*Method)();

    MemberTask(Class* object, Method method, Types&&... args) :
        m_object(object), m_method(method), m_args(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Types>(args)...)) {
    };

    void Execute() override final
    {
        func(m_args);
    };

private:
    Class* m_object;
    Method m_method;
    std::tuple<Types...> m_args;

    template <typename... Args, std::size_t... Is>
    void func(std::tuple<Args...>& tup, TaskHelper::index<Is...>)
    {
        (m_object->*m_method)(std::get<Is>(tup)...);
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    void func(std::tuple<Args...>& tup)
    {
        func(tup, TaskHelper::gen_seq<sizeof...(Args)>{});
    }
};

//************************************************************

template <typename Function, typename... Arguments>
TaskInterface* CreateSimpleTask(Function&& func, Arguments&&... args)
{
    return new SimpleTask<std::result_of<decltype(func)(Arguments...)>::type, Arguments...>(std::forward<Function>(func), std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
}

template <class Class, typename Method, typename... Arguments>
TaskInterface* CreateMemberTask(Class* obj, Method method, Arguments&&... args)
{
    return new MemberTask<std::result_of<decltype(method)(Class)>::type, Class, Arguments...>(std::forward<Class*>(obj), std::forward<Method>(method), std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
}

//************************************************************

class Test {
public:
    Test() { id = ++m_id; }
    bool doIt(int n) {
        std::cout << "doIt of " << n * id;
        return true;
    };

private:
    static int m_id;
    int id;
};

int Test::m_id = 0;


double test1(int xs)
{
    xs *= 555;
    return 66.02l;
}

int main()
{
    TaskInterface* st = CreateSimpleTask(test1, 5);
    st->Execute();

    Test t;

    TaskInterface* mt = CreateMemberTask(&t, &Test::doIt, 66);
    mt->Execute();

    return 0;
}
```

**UPD1:** During compilation I've got following error:

```
error C2664: 'MemberTask<bool,Class,int>::MemberTask(const MemberTask<bool,Class,int> &)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'bool (__thiscall Test::* )(int)' to 'bool (__thiscall Test::* )(void)'
```

Comment: please, post error as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you some corrections

(1) in `MemberTask`, the definition of the `Method` type should include the arguments of the method; so, instead of

```
typedef ReturnType(Class::*Method)();
```

you should write

```
typedef ReturnType(Class::*Method)(Types...);
```

(2) in `CreateSimpleTask()`, instead of

```
return new SimpleTask<
   std::result_of<decltype(func)(Arguments...)>::type,
   Arguments...>(std::forward<Function>(func), std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
```

you should add a `typename` before `std::result_of`, so

```
return new SimpleTask<
   typename std::result_of<decltype(func)(Arguments...)>::type, 
   Arguments...>(std::forward<Function>(func), std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
```

(3) in `CreateMemberTask()` you have forgotten the `typename` and the arguments of the method; so, instead of

```
return new MemberTask<
   std::result_of<decltype(method)(Class)>::type,
   Class, Arguments...>(std::forward<Class*>(obj), std::forward<Method>(method), 
                        std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
```

you should write

```
return new MemberTask<
   typename std::result_of<decltype(method)(Class, Arguments...)>::type,
   Class, Arguments...>(std::forward<Class*>(obj), std::forward<Method>(method),
                        std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
```

Comment: Thank's! Now it works as expected. Actually, it was fixed after your (1) suggestion, but I also applied the other ones. I hate my self for such a moments, when I overlook such details. One's again thank's a lot!