# Defining a variadic template type with unknown argument list as std::map value type

Tags: c++, types, c++14, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I am not sure if this is possible at all what I am trying to achieve the past 3 hours without any sense-making approach.

I have a variadic template like this:

```
template<typename... Ts>
class xunit_test_item {
public:
    template<typename F, typename... Args>
    xunit_test_item(const std::string& name, F&& func, Args&&... args)
    : m_name(name)
    , m_f(std::forward<F>(func))
    , m_args(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {
    }

    // ...

private:
    const std::string m_name;
    std::function<void (Ts...) > m_f;
    std::tuple<Ts...> m_args;
};
```

Above template wraps a test item which is basically a holder of a functor with passed arguments along with a string to name that item.

Objects of that type have to be stored into an std::map as the value type. This is handled in a class that contains an `std::map` container as a member, a registration method to add xunit_test_item items and a run method, that iterates over the map and executes all stored xunit_test_item stored functions.

The class looks basically like this:

```
class unit_test {

    // Define a map type of xunit_test_items
    template<typename ...Ts>
    using testitem_map_t = std::map<size_t, xunit_test_item<Ts...>>;

public:
    unit_test() = delete;
    unit_test(const std::string& group_name)
    : m_tm()
    , m_group_name(group_name)
    , m_test_id(0)
    {

    }
    // Register an functor item
    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    void add_test(const std::string& name, F&& fun, Args&& ...args) {
        m_tm.emplace(++m_test_id, xunit_test_item<Args...>(
            name, std::forward<F>(fun), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

    void run() 
    {
        // ...

        for (auto& t : m_tm) {
            // ...
            t.second->run();
            // ...
        }
    }

private:
    testitem_map_t m_tm; // <-- Compiler correctly reports an error
    std::string m_group_name;
    size_t m_test_id;
};
```

The problem I have is to find the right syntax / different approach to define the `xunit_test_item` as the value type of the `m_tm` map member. The above code is not compiling - without a doubt - as I have to specify an argument list for the `m_tm` member with its type testitem_map_t. I have no idea how to define that type and declare correctly the `m_tm` member. The argument list is unknown at this point.
Perhaps my above classes have a design issue, I wonder if there is a more or less simple way to achieve this. I also may completely fail to see a simple solution.

Would be happy to learn and get a good suggestion. Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Fresh day, fresh try and a cup of coffee ...

I refactored the body of the `add_test` method using a 2-level lambda and that seems to work so far. As test functions (the actual test cases) I can add lambdas, function pointers with arbitrary or no arguments at all.

I don't know if this is the best solution, or if it can be coded in a better way, maybe someone wants to comment on this topic. Also the reason why I do not enter this as an answer. My hope with my initial question was to maybe learn some C++14 sugar as a solution ... if possible.

This is a first roughly tested version ...

```
template<typename F, typename ...Args>
void add_test(const std::string& name, F&& fun, Args&& ...args) {
    std::function<void(Args...)> fun_xargs =
        [name, fun](auto&&... args) {
            std::cout << "  inner lambda\n";
            auto x = xunit_test_item<Args...>(name, fun, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            x.run();
        };

    std::function<void()> fun_void = 
        [=] {
            std::cout << "outer lambda\n";
            fun_xargs(args...);
        };

    m_tm.emplace(++m_test_id, fun_void);
}
```

Comment: wrap `run` in a lambda and store it as a `std::function<void()>` in the map

Comment: Note: the  `Args...` parameter of `xunit_test_item::xunit_test_item` can only ever resolve to a pack convertible to `Ts...`, so you may as well just use `Ts...` there.

Comment: @caleth: Well noted!

Comment: @vu1p3n0x: I do not really understand and as your comment gets upvotes I am curious ... I am inserting a type of `xunit_test_item` and not a function.

Comment: Your `xunit_test_item` erases the functor's type but not the argument types. You need to erase both.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you only need:

```
class unit_test {
public:
    unit_test() = delete;
    unit_test(const std::string& group_name)
    : m_tm(), m_group_name(group_name)
    {

    }

    // Register an functor item
    void add_test(const std::string& name, std::function<void()> f) {
        m_tm.emplace(name, std::move(f));
    }

    void run() 
    {
        // ...
        for (const auto& t : m_tm) {
            // ...
            t.second->run();
            // ...
        }
    }

private:
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> m_tm;
    std::string m_group_name;
};
```

Comment: Looks like my a first version, but I extended it to keep the test function, its arbitrary arguments, the name of the test in a separate template `xunit_test_item`. I just show the constructor, it has a few more methods along with an execution method `run` for the passed in function. BTW, the design is similar to the accepted answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868129/how-to-store-variadic-template-arguments. My current try is a lambda wrapper in the `add_test` method  to add a variadic `xunit_test_item`, but yet I don't know if it solves my problem.

Comment: Which are the features you want from `xunit_test_item` and especially the ones you want to access via `m_tm` ?

Comment: There are not really many methods. The function/functor  composers, a `run` method (actually this is the `run` executed inside `unit_test::run`), last but not least a few getters, the test case name string and a stringified argument getter (args to string) using the std::tuple member. I was happy to have concentrated all that in one template and also a good spot for future enhancements, for example execution timing or the such. But as I see it turns out to be a nightmare when it comes to store these objects into the map. And the lambda try gives me argument deduction problems ...