# Store template parameter pack as a attribute of a non class template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, parameter-passing, variadic-templates

Is it possible to store the variadic template arguments / parameter pack passed to a constructor of a non class template as a attribute of that class **without** turning thatclass into a class template?

I am currently developing a thin wrapper class (I've only created a minimal example here to minimize complexity) that has the following signature:

```
class Wrapper final {
 public:
  template <typename Function, typename... Args>
  auto start(Function&& function, Args&&... args) -> void;
};
```

The parameter pack is passed to the member function template `start<Function, ... Args>` and there is currently no need to "store" either `function` or `args`. Perfect forwarding is used for the further handling within that function.

Now, what I would like to achieve is a signature as follows (introducing an *Interface Class*):

```
class WrapperInterface {
 public:
  virtual ~WrapperInterface() = default;

  virtual auto start() -> void = 0;
};

// TODO(2019-03-17 by wolters) The following is non-working pseudo-code.
class Wrapper final : public WrapperInterface {
 public:
  template <typename Function, typename... Args>
  explicit Wrapper(Function&& function, Args&&... args)
      : function_{function}, args_{args} {
    // NOOP
  }

  auto start() -> void {
    // TODO(2019-03-17 by wolters) Invoke `function_` with `args_`.
    function_(args);
  }

 private:
  std::function<???> function_;
  std::tuple<???> args_;
};
```

Then `Wrapper` could be used as follows:

```
class WrapperClient final {
 public:
  WrapperClient() : wrapper_{[this](){
    // std::cout << "started\n";
  }} {
    // NOOP
  }

 private:
  Wrapper wrapper_;
};
```

Though the *Interface Class* is not required in the example above, it is required in general because the instances should be stored in a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<WrapperInterface>>`.

I've read and tried [How to store variadic template arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868129/how-to-store-variadic-template-arguments), but that approach requires turning `Wrapper` into a class template.

I think something similiar to the [`QThread *QThread::create(Function &&f, Args &&... args)` implementation](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.12/src/corelib/thread/qthread.h#L174) is required. Sadly that code is too advanced for me.

Can you guide me into the correct direction? Is it possible by using a private implementation class template?

Comment: Can't you use a `std::function<void()>` and store `[=]{function(args...);}` in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called type-erasure which is a very interesting technique (example and a shameless self-promotion [here](https://gist.github.com/r3mus-n0x/2f983d3384c23b8be9b3d5e1ad923ae2)), but it's already done for you in `std::function`, so all you have to do is use `std::function<void()>` and use `std::bind` or lambda capture to store the arguments:

```
template <typename Function, typename... Args>
std::function<void()> wrap(Function&& function, Args&&... args)
{
    return [=] { function(args); };
    // or return std::bind(std::forward<Function>(function), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: You've put me on the right track. Using `std::function` was the solution.