# Store variadic template args and use them in another class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to store variadic template arguments in one template class and use them in another. Something like:

```
template<typename... Args>
struct A{
    typedef Args... type; // heh
};

template<typename A_T>
struct B{
    void foo(A_T::type... args){}
};


B<A<int,int> > b;
b.foo(2,3);
```

All help appreciated!

Comment: What about using a tuple? For example, see [Is it possible to “store” a template parameter pack without expanding it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691657/is-it-possible-to-store-a-template-parameter-pack-without-expanding-it?rq=1)

Comment: nice, but how would you extract the parameter pack?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/

Comment: You can't do this without using something like std::tuple. You can't make a typedef of a variadic type list because it's not a "type". Is there a reason why you feel you need to do this? Or is it just out of curiosity.

Comment: Well, another approach is to declare a typedef a tuple in A, and have a foo method in B that takes a tuple. Would it worsen the performance?

Comment: No, tuples are lightweight, stateless, and completely compile-time. There will be no runtime overhead.

Answer (score 3):

You can't define a type as many types! As suggested in all comments `std::tuple` is the right way to have a product type.

```
typedef std::tuple<Args...> type; // instead of typedef Args... type;
```

To achieve the call

```
B<A<int,int> > b;
b.foo(2,3);
```

You can slightly modify your code as

```
template<typename... Args>
struct A{
};

template<typename A_T>
struct B{
};

template<template<typename...> class A_T, typename... Args>
struct B<A_T<Args...>>{
    void foo(Args... args){
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice! Unfortunately I need a solution, that takes some kind of type or a list of types from the A_T.

Comment: @JanekOlszak Can you elaborate. What exactly are you trying to extract from the parameter pack?

Comment: It's a part of my neural network library. The learning takes place in a learn(..) method that can take a different parameter list (depending on how we decide to teach the network).