# Deduce a list of types based on non-type parameter value

Tags: c++, c++17, metaprogramming, crtp

I have a class that can be customized with an undefined number of policies in a variadic template argument:

```cpp
template<typename... Features>
class A : public Features... {};
```

Said features are enabled through bits of a `constexpr uint8_t`, such as:

```
0x1 --> X1 enabled
0x2 --> X2 enabled
0x3 --> X1, X2 enabled
0x4 --> X3 enabled
0x5 --> X1, X3 enabled
etc...
```

How can I write helper types to deduce and forward the correct list of types to `class A`'s variadic template argument?

Using `std::conditional` I could write something like this, but it gets horrendous quite rapidly as you can imagine.

```cpp
using ExtendedA = A<MandatoryFeature, std::conditional_t<HasX1(), X1, std::monostate>;
```

Or uisng helper types and template specialization I could write

```cpp
template<uint8_t value>
struct Features {};

template<>
struct Features<0x3> {
    using type = std::tuple<X1, X2>;
};
```

But then I would need to unpack `Features<0x3>::type` for `class A`'s instance, and I'm not sure how I should write that.

Comment: You may be able to [use this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4693493/4573247).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To transform your flag into collection (tuple) of feature, you might use code similar to:

```
template <std::size_t> struct Feature;

template <> struct Feature<0> { using type = X0; };
template <> struct Feature<1> { using type = X1; };
template <> struct Feature<2> { using type = X2; };
template <> struct Feature<3> { using type = X3; };
template <> struct Feature<4> { using type = X4; };
template <> struct Feature<5> { using type = X5; };
// ...
constexpr std::size_t FeaturesCount = /*..*/;

template <std::size_t Flag, std::size_t...Is>
auto CollectFeaturesImpl(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
-> decltype(std::tuple_cat(
       std::conditional_t<
           (Flag & (1U << Is)) != 0,
           std::tuple<typename Feature<Is>::type>,
           std::tuple<>>
       {}...
   ))

template <std::size_t Flag>
using CollectFeatures_t =
    decltype(CollectFeaturesImpl<Flag>(std::make_index_sequence<FeaturesCount>()));
```

> But then I would need to unpack `Features<0x3>::type` for `class A`'s instance, and I'm not sure how I should write that.

With extra layer, you might "unpack" tuple:

```
template<typename Tuple> struct AFromTuple;

template<typename... Features>
struct AFromTuple<std::tuple<Features...>>
{
    using type = A<Features...>;
};

using myA = AFromTuple<std::tuple<X1, X3>>::type; // A<X1, X3>
```

or

```
template<typename Tuple> struct FromTuple;

template<typename... Features>
struct FromTuple<std::tuple<Features...>>
{
    template <template <typename...> Class C>
    using map = C<Features...>;
};

using myA = FromTuple<std::tuple<X1, X3>>::map<A>; // A<X1, X3>
```

Comment: Very interesting, unless I'm mistaken, the only caveat for my usage (but question was misleading in that regard) is the collector your wrote needs `::type` defined for every value in the sequence. But I can work around that by adding an extra trait and adding an extra check in `std::conditional`. Thanks a ton!

Comment: You can still have alias: `template <std::site_t I> using Feature_t = typename Feature<I>::type;`...

Answer (score 1):

Is too late to play?

Given a list `X1`-`X8` of features, I propose to add a template class that maps number from 0 to 7 to classes `X1`-`X8` and inherit from `X1`-`X8` only if a first boolean template parameter is `true`

```
template <bool, std::size_t>
struct Feature
 { };

template <> struct Feature<true, 0> : public X1 { };
template <> struct Feature<true, 1> : public X2 { };
template <> struct Feature<true, 2> : public X3 { };
template <> struct Feature<true, 3> : public X4 { };
template <> struct Feature<true, 4> : public X5 { };
template <> struct Feature<true, 5> : public X6 { };
template <> struct Feature<true, 6> : public X7 { };
template <> struct Feature<true, 7> : public X8 { };
```

Now a `Feature_helper` struct, that inherit the right `Feature` for every bit in a `std::uint8_t` number, is simple

```
template <std::uint8_t, typename = std::make_index_sequence<8u>>
struct Feature_helper;

template <std::uint8_t u8, std::size_t ... Is>
struct Feature_helper<u8, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
   : public Feature<(u8 & (1 << Is)) != 0u, Is>...
 { };
```

and `A` become

```
template <std::uint8_t u8>
class A : public Feature_helper<u8>
 { };
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

struct X1 { };
struct X2 { };
struct X3 { };
struct X4 { };
struct X5 { };
struct X6 { };
struct X7 { };
struct X8 { };

template <bool, std::size_t>
struct Feature
 { };

template <> struct Feature<true, 0> : public X1 { };
template <> struct Feature<true, 1> : public X2 { };
template <> struct Feature<true, 2> : public X3 { };
template <> struct Feature<true, 3> : public X4 { };
template <> struct Feature<true, 4> : public X5 { };
template <> struct Feature<true, 5> : public X6 { };
template <> struct Feature<true, 6> : public X7 { };
template <> struct Feature<true, 7> : public X8 { };

template <std::uint8_t, typename = std::make_index_sequence<8u>>
struct Feature_helper;

template <std::uint8_t u8, std::size_t ... Is>
struct Feature_helper<u8, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
   : public Feature<(u8 & (1 << Is)) != 0u, Is>...
 { };

template <std::uint8_t u8>
class A : public Feature_helper<u8>
 { };

int main()
 {
   static_assert( true  == std::is_base_of_v<X1, A<5u>> );
   static_assert( false == std::is_base_of_v<X2, A<5u>> );
   static_assert( true  == std::is_base_of_v<X3, A<5u>> );
   static_assert( false == std::is_base_of_v<X4, A<5u>> );
   static_assert( false == std::is_base_of_v<X5, A<5u>> );
   static_assert( false == std::is_base_of_v<X6, A<5u>> );
   static_assert( false == std::is_base_of_v<X7, A<5u>> );
   static_assert( false == std::is_base_of_v<X8, A<5u>> );
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP observe

> Found a downside, class inheriting `Feature_helper` would not be a direct derived class of a `Feature`. Meaning it cannot inherit constructors from `X1`, `X2`, ...

Not sure to understand your requirement but I suppose you can solve the problem (if there isn't collision between `Feature` construnctors) using a lot of `using`.

I've added, in the following example, a `int` contructor for `X1` and a `long` constructor for `X2`.

Observe the `X1() = default;` and `X2() = default;`: adding an explicit constructor the default constructors/destructors are deleted; so you have to re-default them explicitly (maybe also copy/move constructors).

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct X1 { X1(int) { std::cout << "X1 constructor" << std::endl; }
            X1() = default; };
struct X2 { X2(long) { std::cout << "X2 constructor" << std::endl; }
            X2() = default; };
struct X3 { };
struct X4 { };
struct X5 { };
struct X6 { };
struct X7 { };
struct X8 { };

template <bool, std::size_t>
struct Feature
 { };

template <> struct Feature<true, 0> : public X1 { using X1::X1; };
template <> struct Feature<true, 1> : public X2 { using X2::X2; };
template <> struct Feature<true, 2> : public X3 { };
template <> struct Feature<true, 3> : public X4 { };
template <> struct Feature<true, 4> : public X5 { };
template <> struct Feature<true, 5> : public X6 { };
template <> struct Feature<true, 6> : public X7 { };
template <> struct Feature<true, 7> : public X8 { };

template <std::uint8_t, typename = std::make_index_sequence<8u>>
struct Feature_helper;

template <std::uint8_t u8, std::size_t ... Is>
struct Feature_helper<u8, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
   : public Feature<(u8 & (1 << Is)) != 0u, Is>...
 { using Feature<(u8 & (1 << Is)) != 0u, Is>::Feature...; };

template <std::uint8_t u8>
class A : public Feature_helper<u8>
 { using Feature_helper<u8>::Feature_helper; };

int main()
 {
   static_assert( true  == std::is_base_of_v<X1, A<5u>> );
   static_assert( false == std::is_base_of_v<X2, A<5u>> );
   static_assert( true  == std::is_base_of_v<X3, A<5u>> );
   static_assert( false == std::is_base_of_v<X4, A<5u>> );
   static_assert( false == std::is_base_of_v<X5, A<5u>> );
   static_assert( false == std::is_base_of_v<X6, A<5u>> );
   static_assert( false == std::is_base_of_v<X7, A<5u>> );
   static_assert( false == std::is_base_of_v<X8, A<5u>> );

   A<3u>  a1(1);  // call the X1(int) constructor
   A<3u>  a2(2l); // call the X2(long) constructor
 }
```

Comment: Never too late to play the game! I think I like your solution better, it relies on simpler mechanisms and is much more readable, imo. It also does not need anything more to 'skip' unused bits in-between features.  
I'm learning a lot on this one, thanks!

Comment: Found a downside, class inheriting `Feature_helper` would not be a direct derived class of a Feature. Meaning it cannot inherit constructors from `X1`, `X2`, ...

Comment: @Fluffy - Yes... but I suppose you can solve this problem using `using`. Answer improved.